# JAWS execute ctrl click

Tags: accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

We're using JAWS to test accessibility in our web application on IE11.  One of our controls requires a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + click to bring up a context menu.  Is there a way to do this in JAWS with keyboard commands?

Thank you

Comment: Got a Codepen example of what you are trying to enable? Have you looked a ctrl + whatever key is normally used to activate one of those controls? Regardless, you may have to add some instructional text via off-screen or `aria-label` to convey a non-standard control.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically not a good practice to attach context menus to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+Leftclick in an accessible application, unless you have special messages about that. You should think about intercepting the standard context menu keys (Applications/<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>) instead.
However, there is a key combination for that in JAWS, indeed: Ctrl+NumPadSlash, since NumPadSlash simulates the left mouse button click in the JAWS cursor position.
But please note that you navigate the webpage with virtual PC cursor, and not JAWS cursor. So to carry out your command, the user first has to route JAWS cursor to virtual PC cursor (Insert+NumPadMinus), and then execute the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+LeftClick. This is an extremely uncomfortable solution since it is not obvious at all that in this particular place I have to route JAWS to PC and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+click.
Please think about a better approach for JAWS users.